# Arrow Control Not Working For Moving Object

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I currently have this game object and I'm wondering why key control is not functioning. I think its because I have a JTextBox somewhere on a JPanel that I removed that is throwing off the focus. Not entirely sure though.

I used to have the Game class controlling the movement, but this worked once and didn't work again. Again, not sure why.

```
game.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
 if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            object.setVx(-10);
            System.out.println("hello");
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            object.setVx(10);
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            object.setVy(10);
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            object.setVy(-10);
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        object.setVx(0);
        object.setVy(0);
    }
});
```

Here's my attempt at implementing keybinders, which also does not seem to work:

```
public class Main implements Runnable{

public static Game game;

private static final String LEFT = "Left";

private Action left = new AbstractAction(LEFT) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(LEFT);
    }
};
private static final String RIGHT = "Right";
private Action right = new AbstractAction(RIGHT) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(RIGHT);
    }
};

public void run() {

/**here is where I try to put the keystroke in the map
*
*
*/

game.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), LEFT);
game.getActionMap().put(LEFT, left);
game.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), RIGHT);
game.getActionMap().put(RIGHT, right);

/**
*the mouselistener below works
*
*/

// add listeners for the game 
game.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        object.jump();
    }
});

// Start game
Game.reset();
```

This is my compilable and runnable code: it implements the same thing, and it works, I'm pretty sure there is something else in the Game class or in my Main.java that is disrupting the keybinding.

```
public class testKeyBinding implements Runnable {

private static final String LEFT = "Left";
private Action left = new AbstractAction(LEFT) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(LEFT);
    }
};
private static final String RIGHT = "Right";
private Action right = new AbstractAction(RIGHT) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(RIGHT);
    }
};
@Override
public void run() { 
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(800, 800);
    JPanel test = new JPanel();

    test.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), LEFT);
    test.getActionMap().put(LEFT, left);
    test.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), RIGHT);
    test.getActionMap().put(RIGHT, right);

    frame.add(test);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new testKeyBinding());
}

}
```

Comment: Yes, use Key Bindings. The best way to learn them is to try, and the [Key Bindings Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) can help show you how. If you get stuck, ask your question *with* your Key Binding attempt code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've tried using keybindings - see my edits above. Still cannot get keyboard control working. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Please create and post a valid [mcve], code posted here in your question that is compilable, runnable, code with a main method, without dependencies that we have no access to, in short that is testable by us. Then comment back to me and I'll/we'll take a look at it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thank you for the note. I've left the keybinder, the game class and a mouselistener that works. So I'm adding both keybinders and mouselisteners to the game class because the keys should be controlling the velocity of one game object. The mouse should be controlling another motion of another game object.

Comment: I left print statements inside the keybinders so I can just see if it even detects the keyboard, but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: Again, let me know when you post compilable and runnable code in your question, so that I can copy it, paste it into my IDE and run it unchanged. Again, we're looking for a small sample program, not your entire program, and certainly not a link, but runnable -- with a main method, with imports, with all that is needed to simply copy, paste, compile and run.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I posted the context because I don't believe there is anything wrong with the keybinder itself, but something in its environment is preventing it from working. So the third code shows my implementation of just the keybinder in a separate runnable, and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you for that -- so the bottom line to all of this is that you're not yet able to re-create the problem in a small program. I would recommend that you keep working on this, since the only way to solve the problem (short of a complete re-write) is to first isolate and identify it. Keep debugging, and much luck to you!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels do you have any recommendations as to what could be overriding my keybinder? I'm not able to isolate the problem because I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: You have a "problem in code not shown", and I don't know of any way we can help solve these types of problems other than to encourage you to keep debugging, keep trying to isolate the problem, and to wish you luck. 1+ though for the MCVE post.